# The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, "

Tags: c#, image

C# code:

```
 string base64string = Textbox1.Text;
                string converted = base64string.Replace('-', '+');
                converted = converted.Replace('_', '/');
                try
                {
                    //  Convert base64string to bytes array
                    Byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(converted);
                    gif = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(bytes);

                }
```

Textbox1.Text contains

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABUYAAADICAYAAAAkwztuAAAgAElEQVR4Xu3db6wdVd0v8KX2UGlLRfPE8JgIWiUc3yikvqt/ohi1L1Q04u2VCiVq0UpjTIAcCUewxj9YOAakgR7808TEe28rFpOSFKI3xPhGQk1jWyOJN+gLlQYLCtQoT4V7Zj+Z7Zw5s//v2XvNzKdJE+nZs+a3Pr91tvt8z5qZl7y49Cf4Q4AAAQIECBAgQIAAAQIECBAgQIAAgQYJvEQw2qBumyoBAgQIECBAgAABAgQIECBAgAABAi0BwaiFQIAAAQIECBAgQIAAAQIECBAgQIBA4wQEo41ruQkTIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQICAYtQYIECBAgAABAgQIECBAgAABAgQIEGicgGC0cS03YQIECBAgQIAAAQIECBAgQIAAAQIEBKPWAAECBAgQIECAAA....
```

its a correct format but still i am getting error.

Comment: It could be because of `data:image/png;base64,` part in string. Try to remove that.

Comment: also try e.g. http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp just to be sure the full BASE64 text is OK

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to skip this: `data:image/png;base64,`, so try something like:

```
 string base64string = Textbox1.Text.Substring(22);
```

This will fetch everything after the first 22 characters in you string. Note that you might want to verify that there are more than 22 characters in the text-box before doing this, just to make sure it's not empty.

**EDIT:** Perhaps an even better approach would be:

```
var text = Textbox1.Text;
var metadataStart = text.IndexOf("data:image/png;base64,");
if(start != -1)
{
    // Remove the metadata if found
    text = text.Remove(metadataStart, metadataStart + 22);
}
```

After this, you can go ahead and convert `text`.

Answer (score 5):

You need to strip the starting `data:image/png;base64,`. The rest of the string looks like valid BASE64, but everything up to and including the comma does not belong in there.

Answer (score 1):

You need to split this: data:image/png;base64,so try something like

try

{

```
  string base64string = Textbox1.Text.Split(',')[1];
  //Convert base64string to bytes array
   Byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64string);
   gif = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(bytes);
```

}

Comment: Not ok! The first line does not work, as `FromBase64String` returns `byte[]`, not `String`. You want this: `string base64String = Textbox1.Text.Split(',')[1];`. It is unneccessary to perform `ToString` on the `Text` property of a `TextBox` - it is already a `String`. Also you should really make sure that there actually *is*  a comma in `Textbox1.Text`...

Comment: Yes Thorsten Dittmar , Also we should really make sure that there actually is a comma in Textbox1.Text or not.